# Evaluate the limit of $Z(x)$ and $Q(x)$ with their corresponding degree of $m$ and $n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $Z(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, with leading term $a x^n$ , $a>0$, and let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $m$,  with leading term $b x^m$, $b>0$,. Examine $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{Z(x)}{P(x)}$ if
a: $m=n$
b: $m<n$
c: $m>n$

What I figured out was that on the first one that if $m=n$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{Z(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{a}{b}$ but realized that what if the polynomial has other terms, so I got stuck. I really appreciate a good explanation on each not just the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Changed the $Q(x)$ to $P(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the other terms don’t actually matter in the limit. Suppose that

$$Z(x)=ax^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n$$

and

$$P(x)=bx^m+b_1x^{m-1}+b_2x^{m-2}+\ldots+b_{m-1}x+b_m\;.$$

Then

$$\frac{Z(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{ax^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n}{bx^m+b_1x^{m-1}+b_2x^{m-2}+\ldots+b_{m-1}x+b_m}\;,$$

and if $m=n$ this is

$$\frac{Z(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{ax^n+a_1x^{n-1}+a_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+a_{n-1}x+a_n}{bx^n+b_1x^{n-1}+b_2x^{n-2}+\ldots+b_{n-1}x+b_n}\;.$$

Now multiply by $\dfrac{x^{-n}}{x^{-n}}$:

$$\frac{Z(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{a+a_1\left(\frac1x\right)+a_2\left(\frac1x\right)^2+\ldots+a_{n-1}\left(\frac1x\right)^{n-1}+a_n\left(\frac1x\right)^n}{b+a_1\left(\frac1x\right)+b_2\left(\frac1x\right)^2+\ldots+b_{n-1}\left(\frac1x\right)^{n-1}+b_n\left(\frac1x\right)^n}\;.$$

Now what happens when you take the limit as $x\to\infty$ in the numerator and the denominator?